# VideoView in Fragment Overlapping another Fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, fragment

My app is having many fragments, all are working fine but only one fragment which has VideoView overlaps another fragment which has Barcode scanner.
if I insert ImageView instead of VideoView in Fragment then it does not overlaps but with VideoView it overlaps.

Fragment which having videoView:

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_splash_screen, container, false);
        vd = view.findViewById(R.id.adv);
        vd.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getContext().getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.coffee));
        vd.requestFocus();
        vd.start();
        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(getContext());

        vd.setMediaController(mediaController);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(vd);
        vd.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.setLooping(true);
                mp.setVolume(0f, 0f);
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can do is, set background color to parent fragment and make it clickable like below.

[image]